# What are the values of $k$ that males $x_1,x_2$ solutions to the linear system $AX=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Supose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solution to the linear system $ AX=B $ , 
 where $B$ is not equal zero then $3x_1-kx_2$ is a solution also if $k = ?$

How to find the value of $A$ ?

Comment: Assuming $A\neq0$, $Ax_1=B=Ax_2\implies A(x_1-x_2)=0$. So $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran: I suspect $A$ is supposed to be a matrix, in which case $A(x_1-x_2) = 0$ does not necessarily imply $x_1 = x_2$. Of course, this isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: The fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to $AX = B$ means that $Ax_1 = B$ and $Ax_2 = B$.

In order for $3x_1-kx_2$ to be a solution to $AX=B$, we would need $A(3x_1-kx_2) = B$.

We can use linearity to simplify $A(3x_1-kx_2) = 3Ax_1-kAx_2 = \cdots$.

Can you figure out what value of $k$ makes $A(3x_1-kx_2) = B$?

Comment: do you mean that $3x_1−kx_2$ must be equal 0 ?

Comment: No I don't mean that at all. Note that if $y$ is a solution to the equation $AX = B$, then $Ay = B$. So if $3x_1-kx_2$ is a solution to the equation $AX = B$, then $A(3x_1-kx_2) = B$.

Comment: then what is the values of k that makes $x_1 and x_2$ solutions to $AX=B$ could you explain this more please?

Comment: I think the problem given by the first two lines of the lines of the body of your post is saying that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to $AX = B$, and asking you to find a value of $k$ such that $3x_1-kx_2$ is also a solution to $AX = B$. If that's not the problem you are trying to solve, you might want to edit your question.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: I do admit that the later part of my comment is not true as $A$ can be singular. How is $A$ linear then? Since you said in the comment "I suspect $A$ is supposed to be a matrix" (just curious).